# Why is the scanf() getting skipped?

Tags: c, scanf

On executing the code below, the output comes out to be

> Enter activity selected: hello

After taking input for number of activities and entering the activities . The `scanf()` is getting completely skipped.

I tried everything found on the internet like using `getchar()` instead of `scanf()`, putting a `getchar()` before taking input and using `fflush()`.

But nothing seems to be working. Can anyone tell what is the mistake I am making?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name;
    int start;
    int finish;
}activity;

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of activities: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    activity* a = (activity*)malloc(sizeof(activity)*n);
    printf("Enter activities: ");
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c %d %d ",&(a[i].name),&(a[i].start),&(a[i].finish));
    }
    
    //getchar();
    char ch;
    int s,f;
    printf("Enter activity selected:");
    //fflush(stdin);
    //scanf(" %c",&ch);
    ch = getchar();
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a space before the `%c`, so it reads the newline left behind by the previous `scanf`.

Comment: why did you comment `scanf(" %c",&ch);` , that will wait for you to enter,  with `ch = getchar();` you will have to do it manually

Comment: `//scanf(" %c",&ch);` Here there is a space before `%c`.

Comment: I was referring to the `scanf("%c` in the loop. Btw, you should be checking the return value from `scanf` to make sure that it worked.

Comment: @IrAM I was justing testing out `ch = getchar()`, after `scanf(" %c",&ch);` didn't work.

Comment: Since you ask the user to enter complete lines (I guess), I would advice you to use `fgets` + `sscanf`, to divide the problem in smaller parts. Moreover, you should check what is returned by `*scanf`. And to finish, there is some good reading: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: as suggested above you need to give a space before `%c` in `scanf("%c %d %d ",&(a[i].name),&(a[i].start),&(a[i].finish));` also

Comment: @user3386109 That's not working either, neither is using `getchar()` after the loop to eat up the newline.

Comment: You cannot use the same variable in `scanf("%c",%ch)` and for `ch=getchar()`. In the first you need a `char` while the second requires an `int`.

Comment: The typecast to `malloc` is needless.

Comment: Remove `fflush()`. Add the space mentioned before `%c`. Replace `getchar()` with `scanf(" %c",&ch);`.

Comment: Suggest taking all user-input with `fgets()` and then using `sscanf()` to parse values. That way you de-couple the read and conversion. You will read an entire input with each call to `fgets()` and no matter what happens with the conversion it cannot leave characters unread in your input-stream.. Your problem was the `'\n'` left after reading the integer value and then the `'\n'` being taken as input for your `"%c"` conversion specifier. That's just the tip of the iceberg of pitfalls in using `scanf()`. (Ye have been warned...)

Comment: Duplicate [Validating a character input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64673688/3422102)

Answer (score 2):

Remove these unnecessary spaces in `scanf("%c %d %d ",&(a[i].name),&(a[i].start),&(a[i].finish));` and remember to free the memory allocated.

I just modified your code where required, but don't understand the purpose you are reading the last character, since you are not repeating any Menu or something.

anyway this below version works just fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 typedef struct
 {
     char name;
     int start;
     int finish;
 }activity;

 int main()
 {
    int n;
    char ch;
    int s,f;

    printf("Enter number of activities: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    activity* a = (activity*)malloc(sizeof(activity)*n);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter activity details for %d:", i+1);
        scanf(" %c%d%d",&(a[i].name),&(a[i].start),&(a[i].finish));
    }
    
    free(a);
    a = NULL;
    
    printf("Enter activity selected:");
    scanf(" %c",&ch);

    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Enter number of activities: 3                                                                                           
enter activity details for 1:A 1 2                                                                                      
enter activity details for 2:B 3 4                                                                                      
enter activity details for 3:C 5 6                                                                                      
Enter activity selected:E                                                                                               
hello
```